# Why doesn't it like 'self'?

Tags: python, pygame, maze, sys

From 'for wall in walls' onwards all the 'self' in red underlined?

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,16,16)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_dir(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_dir(0, dy)

    def move_dir(self, dx, dy):
        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + dx
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + dy

 #^it accepts all of this...
 # but none of the following...

    for wall in walls:
        if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
            if dx > 0:
                self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
            if dx < 0:
                self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
            if dy > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
            if dy < 0:
                self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom

        for spike in spikes:
            if self.rect.colliderect(spike.rect):
                self.rect.x = 16
                self.rect.y = 16

        if player.rect.colliderect(portal_rect):
            self.rect.x = 528
            self.rect.y = 144

        if player.rect.colliderect(portal_rect1):
            self.rect.x = 176
            self.rect.y = 208
```

unrelated but it also has an issue with portal_rect

Comment: is the second part in your class definition? `self` is only defined inside the class definition

Comment: Is that the actual indentation? Putting plain text in the middle really doesn't help clear this up...

Comment: please post one code that demonstrates the problem ... dont break it into chunks it should be small.  as it stands I would guess that your indentation is broken ...

Comment: I edited it to get rid of the plain text in the middle but now it shows an indentation problem ... so its probably best if you just post a small example for real

Comment: The code from `for wall in walls:` is not inside an instance method, so `self` doesn't exist - it is just running in the class definition scope. If it should be in `move_dir`, it needs more indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation matters!

```
class Example(object):

    def some_method(self):
        # we are inside 'some_method' so 'self' is valid
        self.a = 1

    # we are no longer inside a method so 'self' is not valid
    self.b = 2
```